# Lotusscript NotesDocument values

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I am analyzing a module in lotuscript  which is fetching a NotesDocument .

Now consider as an example the NotesDocument encapsulates the following data :

```
docvalue:<html><head> head </head><body>body</body></html>
```

Now how does the following work?

```
Dim document As NotesDocument    
Dim data as Variant    
' Assume code to fetch NotesDocument has been done.
' statement to fetch html data.    
data=document.docvalue(0)
```

I did not find any Lotus documentation where we can fetch value after ":" as a separator(in this case docvalue: as seen in data above). Please let me know how this works or any link to the documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use [strRight()](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/LSAZ_STRRIGHT.html?lang=en). It gives you the string right from a search string:

```
data=strRight(document.docvalue(0), ":")
```

Answer (score 1):

Knut has the correct answer, if you use Notes 6.x or later (I believe) you can use StrRight().

In addiotion, I would like to point out that the code should be modified slighty. You first declare *data* as a variant, but then you read just the first string value of the field.

If it is a multi value field (and you want all values back, in an array), declare the variable as variant but read the whole field back. If you only want the first value (or if the field only contains one value), declare *data* as String and get the first element like you do.

Also, I hightly recommend not to use the extended notation as you do, use the GetItemValue method of the NotesDocument class instead. It is considered best practices, it is forward compatible, and also faster. I also always capitalize the field names exactly as they are in the document, again for performance reasons. It may not make a difference here, but when you are using for example GetView(), the capitalization does matter.

So your code should look something like this:

```
Dim doc As NotesDocument    
Dim data as String    
Dim html as String
' Assume code to fetch NotesDocument has been done.
' statement to fetch html data.    
data = doc.GetItemValue("DocValue")(0)
html = StrRight(data,":")
Print html
```

Or, if you have muliple values:

```
Dim doc As NotesDocument    
Dim dataArray as Variant    
Dim html as String
' Assume code to fetch NotesDocument has been done.
' statement to fetch html data.    
dataArray = doc.GetItemValue("DocValue")
ForAll item in dataArray
    html = StrRight(item,":")
    Print html
End Forall
```